# What's wrong with my query

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE report_invoice(
'ID' INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'Invoice_No' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
'Invoice_Type' INT(10) NOT NULL,
'Operator' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
'Customer' VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
'Invoice_Date' DATE NOT NULL,
'Total' DECIMAL('10,2'),
PRIMARY KEY ('ID'));
```

I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID'
INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'Invoice_No' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
'Invoic' at line 2
```

Comment: May be its integer instead of int

Comment: @Siva Nope, that didn't work.

Comment: Are you able to specify a length for the data type int? I thought the options were either TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT, INT, BIGINT...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using single quotes around your field names, use backticks instead:

```
CREATE TABLE report_invoice(
`ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Invoice_No` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`Invoice_Type` INT(10) NOT NULL,
`Operator` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Customer` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Invoice_Date` DATE NOT NULL,
`Total` DECIMAL(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But could you explain the difference between using single quotes or backticks?

Comment: @POP86 Single quotes say "this is a string", backticks say "This is a literal, it's not a keyword or a string, but it's all one thing". So this is a valid field name: `ALTER TABLE report_invoice ADD COLUMN \`This is a column with spaces\` VARCHAR(6)`, at the same time it can also just be the same as a keyword: `ALTER TABLE report_invoice ADD COLUMN \`null\` VARCHAR(6)`. In general it's a good idea to avoid anything that will complain if you don't use them, as it's normally a sign that you're doing something strange.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use simple quotes

You may replace them with backticks, or suppress them.

They would be usefull if you want to use reserved keywords as column names (bad idea anyway), or completely numeric column names, or special characters in column names.

So not in your case.

Don't put quotes around decimal scale and precision, too.

So this would do the job.

```
CREATE TABLE report_invoice(
ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Invoice_No VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Invoice_Type INT(10) NOT NULL,
Operator VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Customer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Invoice_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ticks or replace them with back ticks. Same for numbers.

`CREATE TABLE report_invoice(
ID INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Invoice_No VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Invoice_Type INT(10) NOT NULL,
Operator VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Customer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Invoice_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL(10,2),
PRIMARY KEY (ID));`

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE report_invoice(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Invoice_No VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Invoice_Type INT NOT NULL,
Operator VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Customer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Invoice_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Total DECIMAL );
```